# How to change primary key column in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class having an Integer variable 'code'. my requirement is to make 'code', primary key column for that domain and also auto increment and to remove the default 'id' column from the table created for that doamin.thnks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use this :

```
static mapping = {
id name: 'code'
}
```

more informations here : 
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html

Answer (score 9):

Domain classes in Grails by default dictate the way they are mapped to the database using sensible defaults. You can customize these with the ORM Mapping DSL.

Customizes the way the identifier for a domain class is generated with `id`.
See the [Grails documentation for id](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html).

```
static mapping = {
    id column: 'code', type: 'integer'
}
```