# grails, hasMany, set and duplicates

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The grails document says that by default hasMany is a set.
My domain looks like this:

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    String empId;
    String password;
    String contactNumber;
    String emailId;

    static hasMany = [roles : Role]

    static belongsTo = [department : Department]

    static constraints = {
        contactNumber nullable : true
        emailId nullable : true
        empId unique : true
        roles nullable : true
        department nullable : true
    }

    static mapping = {
        sort name : "asc"
    }
}

//Role class
class Role {
    String role;
    String roleId;
}
```

And the following code in the controller allows to add duplicate entries to 'roles':

```
roleListToBeAdded.each { r ->
                        println "Trying to add ${r}"
                        try {
                            employee.addToRoles(r).save(flush:true)
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            println "failed to add ${r}: ${e}"
                        }
                    }
```

why is this so ?

Note: If **roleListToBeAdded** has multiple entries of same role (For, example: if the request JSON looks like this : {"rolesToBeAdded" : [{"role":33}, {"role":33}}) then it is not adding two times, but if say role 33 is already added and I make a new request one more time with role:33, then it adds one more record in 'employee_role' table.

Comment: What does the `Role` class look like, in particular its `equals` and `hashCode` implementations?

Comment: I have edited the post and included the Role class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` to the Role class as Set uniqueness is based on Java equality rather than database identity. The equals definition should be based on the data (e.g. the role name) rather than the database ID, as "transient" instances (those that have not yet been saved) have null ids.

Comment: Here is code for that methods


    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Role)) {
            return false
        }
        other.role == role && other.roleId == roleId
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder.HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append role
        builder.append roleId
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem isn't only in "Set" or in "equals" or "hashcode" implementation but in Role class. This class

```
class Role {
    String role;
    String roleId;
}
```

In this class there are two id: the first is 'roleId' but it isn't a primary key. In fact if you want that 'roleId' be a PK you must add a static mapping to Role class (follow this post [Stack Post, 10120708](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120708/how-to-change-primary-key-column-in-grails)):

```
 class Role {
    String role;
    String roleId;
    static mapping = {
       id column: 'roleId', type: 'varchar'
    }
 }
```

If this mapping isn't set, there is an implicit PK defined as 'id' (the second :) ). If you see the table that the grails framework create reading 'Role' class, you will see something like this:

```
TableName Role
id(This is PK)           role           roleId
---                      ---            ---
```

Tht's why equals/hashcode default method does not seem to work, they make the comparison between implicit id and not between roleId.

bye