# Is it possible to save a specific id for a grails domain object?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am in the process of trying to copy the properties of one domain object to another similar domain object (Basically moving retired data from an archive collection to an active one). However, when I try to save with a manually inputed id the save will not actually put anything into the collection.

```
def item = new Item(style: "631459")
item.id = new ObjectId("537da62d770359c2fb4668e2")
item.save(flush: true, validate: false, failOnError:true)
```

The failOnError does not throw an exception and it seems like the save works correctly. Also if I println on the item.save it will return the correct id. Am I wrong in thinking that you can put a specific id on a domain object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identifier *id* is a somewhat sensitive name to use. If you check your dbconsole, you will find that GORM has provided one for you even without asking. When you use that name for yourself, confusion happens. Grails will respect you with the println stuff, but GORM has the last word on how *id* gets initialized and stored, and it is not listening to you then.

You can rename the *id* to something else like you see in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120708/how-to-change-primary-key-column-in-grails) and maybe then you can use the name *id* for yourself. Otherwise, I suggest leaving *id* to GORM, and have your own identifier for your old keys. You won't have problems retrieving data anyway and there won't be performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was suspecting that was the case but wanted to make sure I was not over looking something silly.

Comment: You're welcome. The answer given by @juandiegoh is correct also, but remember two things here: i) *new Item(id:...)* won't work, so you manually set the *id* with *item.setId(...)* before *save()*, and ii) The burden is on you now to enforce id uniqueness. Therefore, I still recommend you let GORM do the id driving for you.

Comment: Looks like @DavidB is using MongoDB for storage so uniqueness of id will not be a problem since MongoDB's object id are always unique.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the id generator as 'assigned' so then you can put the value that you want and is going to be saved with that value.

```
class Item {

...

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the way you mentioned does indeed work but as @mohsenmadi said above, its added complexity to ensure uniqueness of each item.