# GORM: implement uuid getter while preserving id getter

Tags: grails, grails-orm, uuid

Given you have to keep the existing GORM getter functionality that is based on the default incremental `id`:

**How would you add getter functionality based on a new attribute `uuid`?**

Most desirably there would be something like:

- Overload `get(Long id)` with `get(String uuid)` so that both getters can be used side by side.

In the long run, the performance of the `uuid` getter is critical. So I assume it would be best to make it the primary key.

I'm working on Grails 2.5.4 and will be switching to Grails 3 in the next months. So the solution should be working in both worlds of Grails.

Comment: Why not just use .findByUuid?  Add an index to that field if performance is critical.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, you're right. I think I'm going to do it this way. Please feel free to make it an answer and I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is better to use .findByUuid() and add an index to the field to maintain performance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but i think here is your solution
[How to change primary key column in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120708/how-to-change-primary-key-column-in-grails)

static mapping = {
id name: 'uuid'
}

static mapping = {
    id column: 'uiid', type: 'String'
}